# How to get details of Successful Jenkins build in last x days

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I have a Jenkins pipeline job with name XYZ. There are around 300 builds under XYZ job. I want to write a groovy script that would be used in jenkins to fetch the list of successful Builds in last 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this.

```
import jenkins.model.*

RunList[] myBuilds = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems()
                  .findAll{ it instanceof Job && it.getName() == {your job name} }
                  .collect { it.getBuilds().byTimeStamp({your start date}, {your end date} }
```

Not sure if syntax is is 100% correct, but you can easily figure out what you want to achieve starting from this https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html , which is a root model for your jenkins instance where you can fetch any possible data you may need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it.

Comment: @IGSMI
can you help me to get all job details with last duration I am trying several options but couldnt find any